# C# - How to convert from inherited type to runtime type

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm having trouble with handling the correct type on runtime.

I want my code to dynamically detect which handler should be called based on the parameter type. I don't want to cast a TEvent to the correct type in the code.

All handlers inherit from my interface:

```
public interface IAbstractHandler < in T>  
{
   void Handle(T evnt);
}
```

Example:

```
public class SpecificEventHandler: IAbstractHandler< SpecificEvent>
{
   public void Handle(SpecificEvent evnt) {
    ....
   }
}
```

TEvent.cs:

```
public class TEvent
{
}
```

All the other events used in the handlers derive from TEvent.

Here's some code:

```
List<TEvent> eventItems = new List<TEvent>();
....
foreach (var evt in eventItems) {
  ...
  dynamic eventHandler = ResolveEventHandler(evt.GetType().Name);
  if (evt is MySubtypeEvent subEvent) {
    eventHandler.Handle(subEvent); // <-- this works, but I don't want this.
  }
  eventHandler.Handle(evt); // <-- And this fails, because 'evt' is seemingly 
  // a TEvent even though it's of the correct subclass.
}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to make 'evt' not be a TEvent but rather the real type, but without hard coding it, this would make my 'eventHandler.Handle()' method work (i would assume).

Comment: Do you have any generic constraints on the TEvent type?

Comment: No, it's dead simple, but I'll add the class it to the original post. give me a few seconds...

Comment: You could create and use an extension method "Handle" or similar. In this you can then do the stuff you do with "subEvent" without "polluting" your code in other places.

Comment: @elgonzo: You mean one extension method for every event type?

Comment: Ah, hold on. I might have been wrong. Didn't notice that you only know the EventHandler type from the event's type.

Comment: You could still encapsulate the "subEvent" logic in some static method (in some static utility class), which would be similar to using an extension method...

Comment: @elgonzo but how would I go about 'unboxing' (or whatever the real term is) to the correct type without specificing the type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174329/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-oddbeck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many roads that lead to Rome, and there are quite a few ways you can resolve your problem. One simple approach is to use a generic abstract base class for your concrete event handler types, which can provide a `Handle(TEvent evt)` method.

```
public abstract class HandlerBase<T> where T : TEvent, new()
{
    public abstract void Handle(T evt);


    public void Handle(TEvent evt)
    {
        if (!(evt is T))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("This handler does not support the event type " + evt.GetType().FullName); 
        }

        Handle((T) evt);
    }
}
```

Your specific event handlers would derive from this abstract base class similarly to this code example:

```
public class SpecificEventHandler: HandlerBase<SpecificEvent>
{
   public override void Handle(SpecificEvent evnt)
   {
      ....
   }
}
```

The code from your question could then be simplified like:

```
foreach (var evt in eventItems)
{
    ...
    dynamic eventHandler = ResolveEventHandler(evt.GetType().Name);
    eventHandler.Handle(evt);
}
```

Additionally, to disallow specifiying an event handler with `TEvent` itself as the generic type parameter, declare TEvent as an abstract class or turn it into an interface (note the `new()` constraint i used for *HandlerBase* above, which only allows conrete, instantiable types to be used as generic type parameter). Using `TEvent` itself as generic type parameter for the HandlerBase class i displayed above would result in two *Handle* methods with the same signature, causing a compile error.

Comment: Thanks again, this is just what I needed :)